# How to play audio files to microphone input

Tags: java, android, file, audio, microphone

I was wondering how could I achieve a call chat between me and some other person which the other person does not hear me talk but rather the audio file.

Let's say I own an audio file which contains a voice that says "Hello", he will hear that instead of my voice.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: NO, this is not possible,

this is clearly explained in the [android developer web](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html):

> Note: You can play back the audio data only to the standard output device. Currently, that is the mobile device speaker or a Bluetooth headset. You cannot play sound files in the conversation audio during a call.

the reason why, is not explained in the android web but it must be for sure to avoid criminal actions.